# Pivot table and Dates

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, pivot-table

I am a newbie, and I am sort of a enthusiastic learner, a beginner who is making many mistakes. On my pivot table which is picking up two years worth of dates, I am keen to only choose the first two most recent dates, rather than using a slicer.  I have tried to make it a little bit dynamic, but I am constantly getting error messages,

I was trying to have cells in my spreadsheet which is from date and a two date, or a code that picks the first two most recent dates. I really want the code to work and pulling my hair out, as I have few other pivot tables. Every time I put the cell reference in between, where the dates are I keep getting coding errors.

I want the pivot items more dynamic as like before, I will try to add a validation on the date from and date to make it lot more dynamic.

I want the pivot items to be x first date and y as the second date referring to two cells on the sheet, which I can amend on the sheet, and another code that just picks the first two most recent dates.

```
Sub DateSlection ()

 With ActiveSheet
.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Date")
        .PivotItems("11/2/2016").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("10/26/2016").Visible = True
    End With
    End Sub
```

kind regards

Ali

Comment: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/9/27/vba-guide-excel-pivot-tables take a look there, it should help you :-)

Answer (score 0):

For the dynamic filter you could do something like this:

```
Sub DateSlection ()

Dim startDate As String
Dim endDate As String

With ActiveSheet
    'Set your date parameters in the required date format 
    '- looks like you need US 
    startDate = Format(.Range("A1").Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    endDate = Format(.Range("A2").Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")

    'clear the existing filter and add the new
    .PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Date").ClearLabelFilters
    .PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Date").PivotFilters.Add Type _
            :=xlDateBetween, Value1:=startDate, Value2:=endDate
End With

End Sub
```

I also understand you want to get the first two dates in the pivot table? If so you can do this:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Date").PivotItems(1)
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Date").PivotItems(2)
```

To get the last two dates you can do:

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Date")
    ptCount = .PivotItems.Count
    last = .PivotItems(ptCount)
    secondLast = .PivotItems(ptCount - 1)
End With
```

Comment: i have two years of data, will the below code automatically choose the first two most recent dates

Comment: No - it wont, it will give the first two. I've edited my answer though to include what you need

Comment: I am getting an error message, I am getting invalid or unqualified reference.

Comment: Can you be more specific - what is the actual error message, what line of code are you getting an error on?

Comment: I am getting run time error 1004 The date you entered is not a valid date .PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Date").PivotFilters.Add Type _
            :=xlDateBetween, Value1:=startDate, Value2:=endDate

Comment: Press Alt+F11, click within your sub and press f8 to step through the code. Open the "Locals" window and look at the start and end date values - are they as you expect? Its probably this that is the source of your problem: "mm/dd/yyyy"

Comment: It works on my machine if I change the date format as below, maybe try that:

Comment: startDate = Format(.Range("A1").Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    endDate = Format(.Range("A2").Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")